# How to share a view across various activities

Tags: android, view

Is there any way to share the same object of the View across various activities? For example myApp has 4 activities, and every activity shows a Logo at the top of the screen. Now each activity will initiate 4 copies of the same Logo. So is there any way to get around this?
 And if 3 out of 4 share the same logo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't say that it is completely impossible for you to do that. What I can say with almost certainty is that you should not attempt it or expect anything good to happen if you do manage it. Don't fight the framework, let it work for you. If the duplication is that much of an issue you create an abstract class that your Activities inherit from.

Also, since View's maintain a reference to the Context they were created in. If you did manage to pass a View from one Activity to another you would be creating a memory leak. Since the View would hold a reference to the old Activity via the Context it was created in.

Answer (score 0):

Use seperate layout to make your logo. 
Ex: title.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/headercon" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/headerView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/header" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This layout can be included in any other layout by using include tag

Ex:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

...

<include layout="@layout/title" />
...

</RelativeLayout>
```