# How can I allow multiple activities to share the same inflated "included" view?

Tags: android, view, android-activity

I see this question here, and it makes me wonder if what I'm asking isn't really possible:

[How to share a view across various activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154968/how-to-share-a-view-across-various-activities)

Basically, I have a common footer view that I'm inflating (including) in all of my views. However, it uses the same repetitive code to do that. My thought was to create a parent activity class to do this, but it doesn't seem correct to have one activity render the view of another. So should I just create a utility class of some sort, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include other layout XML files directly in another layout file.  So whenever you set content to a layout file, along comes your footer for the ride.

If your footer needs code to drive it, just create a custom class for it along with the layout file.  Then perhaps during instantiation you can drive the code that needs to execute.

[This](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/) is a blog of how to do it.

Comment: This is not how I ended up doing it because it looked like some people were having issues with the layouts within the include. However, I'm accepting your answer because I think this is the most common way to do it. I instead created a utility class to do the work, and each Activity calls the utility.

Answer (score 1):

include is very useful while reusing View components.

But remember, if any problem occurs while using include tag, wrap the included view by an arbitrary layout.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, another way of having multiple Activities use the same View instance is by doing something like creating your own Application class (it's seriously easy).

MyApplication extends Application ...

@Override
public void onCreate(), onConfigurationChanged(), onLowMemory(), onTerminate(), getIstance().

As there is only a single intance of "Application" that is statically available it makes it a good place to store and share various objects that need to be passed around.